# drawing a straight line using JavaFx?

Tags: java, line, polyline

this code  below can sketch(draw) on anywhere on pane. My question is, how to change this code to make it draw straight lines instead of not straight lines.

As you can see in the picture, i want to convert these lines to straight ones using my code.

["lines"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsVuR.png)

could you help me please, thank you for your efforts.

intended code is below--->

```
/
public class JavaApplication17 extends Application {
Pane canvas;
public static Stack <Object> Lines= new Stack <Object>();
    
double x1;
double x2;
double y1;
double y2;

    public void draw(){
    canvas.setOnMousePressed(e->{

          Lines.push(new Polyline()); 
             
             ((Polyline)Lines.peek()).setStroke(Color.RED); 
        ((Polyline)Lines.peek()).setStrokeWidth(3);
        
        y1 = e.getSceneY();
        x1 = e.getSceneX();
        
        
         ((Polyline)Lines.peek()).getPoints().addAll(x1,y1);
    
      
         canvas.getChildren().add(((Polyline)Lines.peek())); 
          
      });
      
   
      canvas.setOnMouseDragged(e->{
      
        y2 = e.getSceneY();
        x2 = e.getSceneX();
        
          ((Polyline)Lines.peek()).getPoints().addAll(x2 ,y2 );
      });
      
      
      
    
      
    }
    
    
    
  public void start(Stage primaryStage){
      
         
       canvas = new Pane();
       

      draw();
      
      Scene scene = new Scene(canvas,1080,720);
     
      primaryStage.setScene(scene);
      primaryStage.show();
      
  }
  
      public static void main(String[] args) {
       Application.launch();
    }
}
```

Comment: "*As you can see in the picture...*" - What picture? --- Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: sorry, i will change it

Comment: It's best to describe your algorithm in text. We help best if there are actual bugs that we can find.